# Pass domain list to view with specific element removed

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm using grails 1.3.7.

I have the following Domain:

```
class Category {

    String name;
    String categoryKey;

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static constraints = {
        name(blank: false, nullable: false, maxSize:30)
        categoryKey(blank: false, nullable: false, maxSize:30)
    }

    String toString()
    {
        return name
    }
}
```

I display the list of categories in gsp as follows:

```
 <g:select class="fields" valueMessagePrefix="shared.category.label" name='categoryKey'
              value="${dealInstance?.category?.categoryKey}"
              noSelection="${['': message(code: 'layouts.main.filter.select', default: '(Please select one)')]}"
              from='${categoryList.list()}' optionValue="name"
              optionKey="categoryKey"></g:select>
```

I need to display the list with one of it's items removed (Where categoryKey property equals OTHER).

```
def Category categoryList = Category
//categoryList.categoryKey.remove("OTHER") How to remove here maybe?
return [dealInstance: dealDetails, categoryList: categoryList ]
```

How can I remove this in my controller and pass the new list (Minus OTHER) to the gsp?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [findAll](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) collection function and use the closure to check for the object you want to remove.

From the documentation:

```
assert [2,4] == [1,2,3,4].findAll { it % 2 == 0 }
```

So you can do something like:

```
categoryList.findAll { << return false if 'it' is of type 'OTHER', otherwise true >> }
```

You can also use this oneliner directly in your view if you like.

Comment: Thanks micha. I get the following error with <>:
Groovy:unexpected token: < @ line 48, column 41.

Comment: Have you just copied my code into your groovy file? Within `< .. >` it is just pseudo code because i didn't know the structure of you object in detail. You have to replace it with your own filter expression.

Comment: Just relizied that micha! Ooops!

Comment: So I have the following micha: def Category categoryList = Category.findAll { !it.categoryKey.equals('OTHER') } but am getting error "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.deals.Category.findAll() is applicable for argument types:". Any ideas? – Thomas Buckley 5 mins ago

Comment: `findAll` is a collection function. So you have to call on your list. Like `<the list you want to filter>.findAll { .. }`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help micha.
def categoryList = Category.list().findAll { !it.categoryKey.equals('OTHER') }

Answer (score 0):

You can update **toString()** in grails domain to do this.

in toString()     return name + ", " + categoryKey+ ", " + lastUpdated

I am displaying fields without dateCreated.

You can display fields by using above code as per ur requirement.